# Keep first three characters across every column in a dataset

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lapply, tidyverse

```
data <- data.frame( ANNO801 = sample(c("1/1:0,10:10:30:1|1:55111119_C_A:450,30,0", "0/0:8,0:8:24:.:.:0,24,282")), ANNO802 = sample(c("1/1:0,5:5:15:1|1:44449611_C_T:225,15,0", "0/0:4,0:4:12:.:.:0,12,165")))
```

Hi everyone,

So, I want to keep only the first three characters of every column across the entire dataset.

I've tried:

```
PracticeINV$ANN0801 <- substr(PracticeINV$ANN0801, 0, 3)
```

But this only works on the first column. How do I use something like dplyr or lapply to automate it for the entire dataset.

I'm not sure if this needs a minimum reproducible example, but I'll give one if need be!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: Here you go: 
 
`data <- data.frame(
    ANNO801 = sample(c("1/1:0,10:10:30:1|1:55111119_C_A:450,30,0", "0/0:8,0:8:24:.:.:0,24,282")),   
    ANNO802 = sample(c("1/1:0,5:5:15:1|1:44449611_C_T:225,15,0", "0/0:4,0:4:12:.:.:0,12,165")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution with `lapply`.

```
data2 <- data
data2[] <- lapply(data2[], function(x) substr(x, 1, 3))
data2
#   ANNO801 ANNO802
# 1     1/1     1/1
# 2     0/0     0/0
```

A solution using `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

data2 <- data %>% mutate_all(list(~substr(., 1, 3)))
data2
#   ANNO801 ANNO802
# 1     1/1     1/1
# 2     0/0     0/0
```

**DATA**

```
set.seed(123)

data <- data.frame( ANNO801 = sample(c("1/1:0,10:10:30:1|1:55111119_C_A:450,30,0", "0/0:8,0:8:24:.:.:0,24,282")), ANNO802 = sample(c("1/1:0,5:5:15:1|1:44449611_C_T:225,15,0", "0/0:4,0:4:12:.:.:0,12,165")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, colnames(df) :=  lapply(.SD, function(x) substr(x, 1, 3)),
          .SDcols = colnames(df)][] # you can use .SDcols to specify some columns in you want
```

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_at(vars(colnames(df)), list(~ substr(., 1, 3))) # you can use vars() to specify some columns in you want
```